# SVN Repository not able add .so files

Tags: ubuntu, svn

I am doing an cordova project and have my code base at SVN and using ubuntu. I have Jar files that has .so files as dependencies (https://superuser.com/questions/71404/what-is-an-so-file) . I am unable to commit these files in svn .

When i give  `svn status --no-ignore` i get the path of the file with preceeding   `I`.

When i give  `svn proplist` i am not getting any properties for my repositary any way to fix this ???

Comment: Why is this tagged with `git`?

Comment: Sorry removed and updated my answer !

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't be committing compiled code into version control. Your build system should do the compilation using the raw source files.

Answer (score 12):

Finally found answer for my own question .

The problem was svn has some global ignore list which u can find in svn config file.

```
# global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo __pycache__
```

So what i did was added each .so file manually by the command

```
 svn add "********.so" --no-ignore
```

And when i tried committing it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than adding each file one at a time, add them all at once with a target file. Create list:

```
svn status --no-ignore > ignored-files
```

Open in an editor and delete the first 8 columns. In notepad++, holding the alt key allows column selection. Add listed files:

```
svn add --targets ignored-files --no-ignore
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done it like it:

`find . -name "*.so" > list_to_be_committed`

`svn commit --targets list_to_be_committed`